# Window Function inside of Common Table Expression DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2, common-table-expression

I am trying to write a window function inside of a common table expression on Db2 and receiving some unexpected errors

This query works on Db2 11.5.7

```
WITH dummy AS(
    SELECT 1 AS rowValue, 0 AS phase from sysibm.sysdummy1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS rowValue, 0 AS phase from sysibm.sysdummy1

),
solution(rowValue, phase) AS (
    SELECT b.rowValue, phase FROM dummy a,
        TABLE(
        select a.rowValue AS rowValue
        from dummy as b
        ) b
    WHERE phase = 0
) 
SELECT * FROM solution WHERE phase = 1;
```

However this query:

```
WITH dummy AS(
    SELECT 1 AS rowValue, 0 AS phase from sysibm.sysdummy1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS rowValue, 0 AS phase from sysibm.sysdummy1

),
solution(rowValue, phase) AS (
    SELECT b.rowValue, phase FROM dummy a,
        TABLE(
        select max(a.rowValue) AS rowValue
        from dummy as b
        ) b
    WHERE phase = 0
) 
SELECT * FROM solution WHERE phase = 0;
```

fails with an error

```
SQL0206N  "A.ROWVALUE" is not valid in the context where it is used.
SQLSTATE=42703
```

Interestingly if perform some scalar operation on `a.rowValue` though I can retrieve it. For example the following query DOES work.

```
WITH dummy AS(
    SELECT 1 AS rowValue, 0 AS phase from sysibm.sysdummy1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS rowValue, 0 AS phase from sysibm.sysdummy1

),
solution(rowValue, phase) AS (
    SELECT b.rowValue, phase FROM dummy a,
        TABLE(
        select max(a.rowValue*b.phase) AS rowValue
        from dummy as b
        ) b
    WHERE phase = 0
) 
SELECT * FROM solution WHERE phase = 0;
```

This query also works.

```
WITH dummy AS(
    SELECT 1 AS rowValue, 0 AS phase from sysibm.sysdummy1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS rowValue, 0 AS phase from sysibm.sysdummy1

),
solution(rowValue, phase) AS (
    SELECT b.rowValue, phase FROM dummy a,
        TABLE(
        select max(a.rowValue*b.phase) AS rowValue
        from dummy as b
        group by a.phase
        ) b
    WHERE phase = 0
) 
SELECT * FROM solution WHERE phase = 0;
```

Given that the above query works and produces the expected result I would also expect this query, which is the one i really want, to work.

```
WITH dummy AS(
    SELECT 1 AS rowValue, 0 AS phase from sysibm.sysdummy1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS rowValue, 0 AS phase from sysibm.sysdummy1

),
solution(rowValue, phase) AS (
    SELECT b.rowValue, phase FROM dummy a,
        TABLE(
        select max(a.rowValue*b.phase) over (partition by a.phase) AS rowValue
        from dummy as b
        ) b
    WHERE phase = 0
) 
SELECT * FROM solution WHERE phase = 0;
```

but it fails with this error.

```
SQL0206N  "ROWVALUE" is not valid in the context where it is used.
SQLSTATE=42703
```

Which is interesting because I would expect the error to be this:

```
SQL0206N  "A.ROWVALUE" is not valid in the context where it is used.
SQLSTATE=42703
```

I really would like to use a window function here but not sure how to achieve it given these errors. I'm looking for either a. An explanation as to why these queries don't work or b. an alternate syntax that would achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You should open a case with IBM support on this.
Possible workaround might be to inject some expression using some inner table column, which doesn't influence the result.

```
WITH dummy AS(
    SELECT 1 AS rowValue, 0 AS phase from sysibm.sysdummy1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS rowValue, 0 AS phase from sysibm.sysdummy1

),
solution(rowValue, phase) AS (
    SELECT b.rowValue, phase FROM dummy a,
        TABLE(
        select 
          max(a.rowValue + coalesce(b.rowValue, 0)*0) AS rowValue
        from dummy as b
        ) b
    WHERE phase = 0
) 
SELECT * 
FROM solution 
WHERE phase = 0
```

| ROWVALUE | PHASE |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9USHwCMM)